# Bluetooth 4.0 - stream mode

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, android, bluetooth-low-energy

I want to use Bluetooth 4.0 protocol for stream communication between MCU(STM32) and Android/iPhone smartphone. Does Bluetooth 4.0 supports any other case scenario than usual(Heart monitoring, fitness etc.)?

To be specific in this datasheet http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1863900.pdf I've found stream mode, but I am not sure is that a marketing or not?

Thank you!

EDIT: To be precise, I want to stream data from STM32 over Bluetooth 4.0 protocol to Android/iOS with baudrate higher than 115200. Can I do that with smarthpones which have Bluetooth 2.0 in it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it should be possible because any Bluetooth device with versions 2.0 supports a data rate of 3Mbps(3000000 bits/sec) however practically you can attain 2Mbps so by either way the answer to your question is yes !

Comment: In that case I cannot certify the app to work with iOS.

Comment: Bluetooth Smart, i.e. Bluetooth 4.0 single mode does not support 3Mbps transmissions. The linked device is clearly a Bluetooth 4.0 single mode device where the data throughput is a few kilobytes per second. -1.